# The "on hold" description seems to be directed at me, even when I didn't ask the question

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, on-hold

I have edited a question and it is now been put on hold. I went to check if there had been any new activity when I noticed the banner/label that is written as if you are the one that has asked the question. I find this a bit irritating and I think it should be fixed so that only the one that has asked the question sees the information label.

[image: Information label]

Comment: _IOS app reacts like if it is your own question_ Can you clarify? Even the site shows a question is closed/on hold for anyone who visits it..

Comment: @SurajRao it shows it in the title yes but on the app i get this little label in The bottom of The screen where it says "Put on hold as unclear what you're asking"

Comment: In the site it shows the banner. The app seems consistent with the site.I just  felt there was a misunderstanding because of that statement

Comment: I haven't noticed it on site before, but it still irtitates me that it is writen as if i am The one that asks

Comment: I think it’s the use of the “you’re” rather than “the asker” that’s the problem here. It’s written as if you are the OP and not a passerby.

Comment: Could also be written as "unclear what is being asked"